# Adobe Illustrator CS6

Tags: fonts, adobe-illustrator

When I open a particular file, Illustrator tells me some fonts are missing and it's substituting others. That's fine, because the fonts are the ones I want to use anyway. Now how do I make the substitutions permanent?